# Permission denied (publickey) - Digital Ocean

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

This is definetly a duplicate but I went through as many of the other answers as I could, I posted on the Digital ocean forum first, and I contacted DO support, and still I cannot access my server.

I tried:

1. Used `ssh-keygen` and make a key called id_rsa3 (id_rsa works, but this is already taken). Adding the SSH key on creation to the DO dashboard via copy/paste. This method did not work. I destroyed the droplet and began again.
2. Recreated new keys and did `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa3 root@MY-IP`. Then did `ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa3 root@MY-IP` to test. `Permission denied (publickey).`
   I destroyed the droplet and began again.
3. Recreated new keys. Login into DO console and go to `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys` and paste in the public key that matches my local key. Then `ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa3 root@MY-IP` to test. Still, `Permission denied (publickey).` Destroy droplet, try again.
4. Created a `~/.ssh/config` and tried to get the droplet to choose the correct key. Might be some syntax problems here. It runs the config, but does not get the correct key.

   `Host sinatra_app
     HostName 206.***.***.*04
     AddKeysToAgent yes
     UseKeychain yes
     User root
     PubKeyAuthentication yes
     IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa3
     IdentitiesOnly yes`

UPDATE:
Destroyed droplet and added new keys. It asks me for a PW even with SSH. If I changed the `PasswordAuthentication no` it will then say `Permission denied (publickey).` So this is where I am stuck now. With access but cannot remove PW.

Comment: are you sure you copied your public key, not private one?

Comment: I was not including the .pub so this could be the issue. But, I remove old key `ssh-keygen -R root@MY-IP`. Make new `ssh-keygen`, then add `.pub` just to be sure I am doing correct. `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa3.pub root@MY-IP` . `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: did you solve the problem? please share your ideas too if you have any

Comment: I wasn't able to remove the password a couple of times for different reasons. 1.) I created the SSH keys on Ubuntu, and tried to use them on Windows. I had to change the encoding of the SSH keys to be compatible with Windows. 2.) I had used the "sudo" command to copy the SSH keys to Ubuntu, and I used the "~" shortcut to reference the home directory. This stored the SSH keys in the ".ssh" directory for the root user. I had to copy the SSH keys to the ".ssh" directory for the non-root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better answer where I solved this properly. https://serverfault.com/questions/938870/rampant-permission-denied-publickey-mac

<strike>I solved this, very poorly. This is a sloppy way to get access. It still asks for PW even with SSH but at least there is no public key error.
 ~1. Destroy- `Permission denied (publickey)` droplet
 2. Recreate-if this is not first droplet DO NOT add SSH key to
    control panel. It won't know which private key to connect to
 3. Create- new key- `ssh-keygen`
 4. Copy- new key to server- `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/new_keyname root@MY-IP`
 5. Test- `ssh -i ~/.ssh/new_keyname root@MY-IP`~</strike>

But will still ask for PW. Turning off PW (in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config => PasswordAuthentication no)` means removes all PW access (I know it is not supposed to, but it still does. I mean, it removes SSH and PW access so there is no access). I had to reset the root PW from the control panel under `access`, or recreate the droplet

Comment: You can add a public key for the root user when you create the droplet in the web interface. https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/to-account/

Comment: How does it know which private key to connect to? Maybe I missed that. That is one of my main problems.

Comment: You typically create keys as a matching pair (for example using `ssh-keygen`). So the public key was generated at the same time as the private key. Like a key and a padlock. The public key file contains a plaintext name at the end, which you can use to identify it.

Comment: I think ssh just tries all the public keys you added for that user until one works. If none of the public keys are right, it will fall back to password if that's enabled on the server. The ssh client will use the private key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`   by default. If you have multiple private keys, you can use `-i ~/.ssh/other_key` or create a `~/.ssh/config` file with host specific config (private key name, login name, etc). Read `man ssh config` for full docs.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for the [serverfault.se], [security.se] or [unix.se] stackexchange communities instead of stackoverflow. Server Fault even has a [digital-ocean](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/digital-ocean) tag.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with my local config that stops the public from finding the correct private. I'll work on migrating this to the other Stack Exchange and see if I can repost this there instead.

Comment: When you use a ssh config with `Host sinatra_app` then you should not need to give a hostname/ip directly to the ssh command, or username or identity file/private key file. Simply `ssh sinatra_app` with no further arguments should work. Did you try that?

Comment: You can use the digital ocean web-based login shell, login as root and inspect the ssh server logs to find more diagnostics about why your login failed. They can be found at `/var/logs/auth.log` (there's typically a lot of failed bot logins there too. Just bots trying random ips with common username / password pairs. So if you want to allow password login, make sure you are using a strong password)

Answer (score 6):

i had the same issue, and to solve it , you open digitalocean , open console
as in web and login with your root password,

then `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
and change **PasswordAuthentication** from no to `yes`
save and restart by `sudo service ssh restart`

that's all.

Comment: After days of checks and reloads and copying it appears the only thing that I missed out was the -sudo service ssh restart-.  THANK YOU EDMOND